# Android, SQLite, создание базы данных

Tags: java, android

Я немного не понимаю. При вызове (а точнее создании базы данных), разве не должен вызываться метод onCreate? Вот код базы данных:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    String name;
    final String TAG = "APP";
    final String MSG = "БАЗА ДАННЫХ: ";

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, 1);
    }

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name) { 
        super(context, name, null, 1);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "создание таблицы " + name);

        if (name.equals("dictionaries")) {
            db.execSQL("create table "
                    + name + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + "dictionary"
                    + " String);");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "создание таблицы 1"); 
            db.execSQL("create table "
                    + name + "_verb" + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + "last"
                    + " String, " + "currently" + " String, " + "next"
                    + " String, " + "translate + String);");
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "создание таблицы 2"); 
            db.execSQL("create table "
                    + name + "_noun" + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + "word"
                    + " String, " + "translate" + " String);");
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "создание таблицы 3"); 
            db.execSQL("create table "
                    + name + "_phrase" + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + "phrase"
                    + " String, " + "translate" + " String);");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {      
    }
}
```

После вызова несуществующей таблицы, в лог выводит сообщение только из конструктора DBHelper, а метод не запускается. Это нормально или так не должно быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6791968/3212712) и [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5024277/3212712)

Проблема здесь в том, что в конструкторе вы явно не вызываете метод **onCreate**() и в конструкторе супер-класса этого вызова тоже нет. 
Чтобы его вызвать вы можете просто в коде вызвать методы получения объекта БД и она будет создана, если ещё не создана (т.е. будет вызван метод **onCreate**())

```
DBHelper dBHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
dBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//или
//dBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```